# How to design inline button in the text field using flutter

Tags: flutter

Good day! i'm trying to put an inline button on the text field for my "get a code" function but no success. i tried to search for some tutorials but never met or found what i'm looking for. i'm using vscode for my IDE.

[Get a Code button]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPhiP.png

here's my code for that particular text field:

```
const SizedBox(height: 10),
    TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Code",
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              borderSide: BorderSide.none),
          fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
          filled: true,
          prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.code)),
      obscureText: true,
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm Try To solve Your Problem :**

**Here is Code**

```
      return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              body: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
        
                
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0,horizontal: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
        
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 0
                            ),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Code",
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.code,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          width: 110,
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 1,
                          ),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
        
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            "Get A Code",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )

;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could assign any widget to suffix property.
You could use `InkWell, Gesturedetector, TextButton()`

```
TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Code",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                ),
                fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                filled: true,
                suffix: InkWell(
                  child: Container(                    
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        30,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Get a Code',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    print('Code sent');
                  },
                ),
                prefixIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.code,
                ),
              ),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
```

Comment: thanks pawandeep Singh, but it did not work